a question in Integration by parts
I have two functions $f\in H^{1}(\Omega)$ and $g\in H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)$ where $\Omega$ is a bounded smooth domain.
Then I consider the integral
\begin{align}
\int_{\Omega}f^{\prime}g dx=-\int_{\Omega}fg^{\prime}dx
\end{align}
which is caused by integral by parts and vanishing boundary of $g$.
Then I have a maybe stupid question. For a constant $b\in\mathbb{R}$, $f+b\in H^{1}(\Omega)$, since $\Omega$ is bounded. I call $f+b=\tilde f$ and obviously $\tilde{f}^{\prime}=f^{\prime}$
so
\begin{align}
-\int_{\Omega}fg^{\prime}dx=\int_{\Omega}f^{\prime}gdx=\int_{\Omega}\tilde{f}^{\prime}g dx=-\int_{\Omega}\tilde fg^{\prime}dx
\end{align}
This is obviously impossible. But can someone tell me where is the mistake?

Your last integral unravels into $\int_\Omega fg'dx + b\int_\Omega g'dx$, which doesn't match the original relationship unless you choose $b$ to be $0$ or $\int_\Omega g'dx$ evaluates to $0$.

In your original equality, if $f\equiv1$, what happens to the integral of $g’$?

Why is this "obviously impossible"?
